# Use of tense for past event

Tags: past-tense, past-vs-past-perfect

My colleague was not at his desk hence I received his call and replied. After one hour he returned to his desk and now I want to tell him about that call

How do I tell him?

> Xyz had called you.

Should I refer long past?

> Xyz called you.

Should I just inform him about call?

Or

> Xyz did call you.

Should I refer recent past?

Comment: As an American English speaker, I would just say "XYZ called you".  But I think there is a more important point: the different tenses and phrasings  *has called/called/did call* are not about long past vs. recent past!  Rather, they're about relating events in the past to a different time.  It might help to review all of the English past tenses: http://www.englishtenses.com/past_tenses

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stress that the action has taken place recently:

> Хуz has just called you.

or you can simply mention what happened an hour ago:

> Xyz called you an hour ago.

There's no need to use past perfect or emphasis *did call*.

Answer (score 0):

This is an action referring to the past event. You just want to let the person know that 'Xyz' had called their phone but they weren't there, so you answered it instead.

So 'Xyz called your phone while you were away and I answered'... would be appropriate enough.

Remember there are many ways to express a sentence in English that mean the same thing, whether it be in the past, present or future :

i.e - ('The man had finished his meal' - compared to 'The man already ate his food' ...etc (past))

('The man will finish his meal' - compared to 'He will eat his food later' (future))